# Highcharts exporting button id

Tags: css, highcharts, jsfiddle

The _id in the following code example doesn't seem to work any more:

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        'myButton': {
            _id: 'myButton',
            symbol: 'diamond',
            x: -62,
            symbolFill: '#B5C9DF',
            hoverSymbolFill: '#779ABF',
            onclick: function() {
                alert('click!')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I check the exporting.js it is removed in latest version? How can we identify a button now?

Is there also an easy way to update the button symbol image dynamically? Like when clicking the button it changes the image of that button.

http://jsfiddle.net/fXHB5/8137/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you were using some kind of workaround - I can suggest another approach: http://jsfiddle.net/tw576/

But still this is only workaround, so one day this may be changed.

```
var buttonTitle = 'updated title',
    container = $("#container").highcharts(),
    buttonLength = container.exportSVGElements.length;

container.exportSVGElements[buttonLength - 1].attr('title', buttonTitle);
```

Or you can use `$(".highcharts-button")` to update one of buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It works nice, only drawback is that it relies on a fixed position in the array.

Comment: Yes, that's true. You can compare previous titles or something like that to make sure you are changing proper button title.